# Find $x\in \mathbb{R}$ so $e^{x}-1=x(e-1)$

Tags: real-analysis, exponential-function, roots

Find $x\in \mathbb{R}$ so $e^{x}-1=x(e-1)$

I tried using Fermat theorem, but I'm not sure that $f= e^{x}-1-x(e-1)$is increasing

Comment: How about $x=1$?

Comment: Well, one solution is obvious, no?

Comment: How about $x = 0$?

Comment: Alas, it's not.

Comment: @Arthur has found you another great one

Comment: Perhaps you have in mind the Intermediate Value Theorem?  When you mention a function $f$, it is not obvious what you have in mind.  The equation has left- and right-hand sides that are both increasing as functions of $x$, but this is probably not as important as the continuity of both.  Please edit the Question to clarify what you are asking.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg: One does not need "analysis" tag when you have "real analysis". Indeed "analysis" is not specific enough and is not suggested in general. Please read the tag info for "analysis" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/analysis/info)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $f(x)=e^x-1-x(e-1).$

Thus, $f''(x)=e^x>0,$ which says that $f$ is a convex function.

Hence, our equation has two roots maximum.

But $0$ an $1$ they are roots and we are done!

Comment: How did you ensure that if $f$ is convex then it has maximum two roots?

Comment: By definition of a convex function $f$ the graph of $f$ is placed under all chord. I think it's clear now. Draw it!

Comment: Yes. I could understood.

Answer (score 1):

You could have checked it easily with graphs .
The graph of $y=e^x-1$ goes as

[image]

While that of $y=x(e-1)$ goes as

[image]

Hence the graph of $e^x-1=x(e-1)$

[image]

Note: 
This could also have been done manually.

Hence our solutions are $x=0,1$